# Receiving a Complie Error method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, compilation

I'm creating a shared worksheet - In column O, when they click I have a User form created asking 3 questions. I need those answers to be put into a hidden worksheet. I've written the code, but when I run it, I get the compile error method. Since I'm so new to VBA, I'm sure I'm missing something I don't understand. There is prob all kinds of errors I'm missing. This is my first one that I haven't just copied and pasted. So any help would be greatly appreciated! IN this case, I googled and found a form that was about what I was looking for and tried to adjust it to fit what I needed it to be. Probably my first mistake!!

It is highlighting the

```
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=x1Rows, _
        SearchDirection:=x1Previous, LookIn:=x1Values).Row + 1
```

Here is my entire code. Please please help!

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("WebLeadInfo")

    'find first empty row database
   iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=x1Rows, _
        SearchDirection:=x1Previous, LookIn:=x1Values).Row + 1

    'check for a contact
    If Trim(Me.txtContact.Value) = " " Then
        Me.txtContact.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter info"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'copy the data to the database
    'use protect and unprotect lines,
    '   with your password
    '   if worksheet is protected
    With ws
    '   .Unportect Password:="sunway12"
       .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtContact.Value
       .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtFind.Value
       .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtSearch.Value
       .Protect Password:="sunway12"
    End With

    'clear the data
    Me.txtContact.Value = " "
    Me.txtFind.Value = " "
    Me.txtSearch.Value = " "
    Me.txtContact.SetFocus


End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **documantation for Find method** you can see that
**parameter SearchOrder** can be one of the following **XlSearchOrder** constants:

```
xlByRows
xlByColumns
```

And **SearchDirection** can be one of the following **XlSearchDirection** constants:

```
xlNext  
xlPrevious
```

Finally **LookIn** parameter should be set to:

```
xlValues
```

So in your case it would be:

```
'find first empty row database
Dim findResult As Range
Set findResult = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)

iRow = 1 ' in case that the sheet contains no data the first empty row is the first one
If (Not findResult Is Nothing) Then iRow = findResult.Row + 1

' ...

With ws
'   .Unportect Password:="sunway12"
   .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtContact.Value
   .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtFind.Value
   .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtSearch.Value
   .Protect Password:="sunway12"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I made sure it looks exactly like that now. It accepted it and moved on to new error... I can't wait till I learn VBA better!

Comment: You are amazing!!! How I miss those little things I'll never know! Thank you soooo much!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

x1Rows (and the others as well). 
They are using a "one" character in there. But they should be spelled with "L"
XLROWS, not X1ROWS

Comment: Ahh.. I thought I changed those! Thank you! Now to see what errors I get next  :o)

Comment: Is there a place that someone might help me walk through this ?? I think I'm in above my head! I've received a new error.   Run-time error 1004, Application defined or object defined error. I assume I'm getting these because I tried to alter a code to fit my purposes :( booo!

Comment: You need to change the `Cells(lRow...` to `Cells(iRow...` so it can pick up the correct variable.

Comment: .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtContact.Value

Comment: I'm sure it's because I changed a previous written code to try and match what I needed. I'm probably leaving something out. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Hey, go to the preferences of the VBA editor and check the option to require explicit variable declaration (or write at the very first line of every code module "Option Explicit". That will avoid many troubles with bad word spelling, because every name you use MUST be declared with "dim name as something"